# How to use javascript in Golang to get a specific website elements or submit forms

Tags: javascript, html, qt, go, qt5

I used Qt before Golang, I can use javascript in Qt like this:

```
QWebView* view = new QWebView(parent);
view->load(QUrl("http://www.example.com"));
QString cmd("example.value = \"test\""); //using javascript to fill value
view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(cmd);

QString cmd2("document.forms[\"Form1\"].submit()");//using javascript to submit a Form
QVariant result = view->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript(cmd2);
qDebug() << result.toString(); //get javascript return data
```

How can I use javascript in Golang to get a specific website elements or submit forms.

Comment: Are you running Go on the client side, or on the server?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I use javascript in Golang

You can use [**gopherjs**](https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs), a compiler from Go to JavaScript.

You can see an example in the [`tidwall/digitalrain`](https://github.com/tidwall/digitalrain) project, where the [`digitalrain.go`](https://github.com/tidwall/digitalrain/blob/8a6813628b4ee1642765923f6eff4fbed226193b/digitalrain.go) file access html elements

```
js.Global.Get("document").Get("head").Call("appendChild", sheet)
js.Global.Get("document").Set("title", "whoa")
```

(for [a great effect](http://tidwall.github.io/digitalrain/))

Comment: Is there any example to get elements or submit forms from a target URL

Comment: @GreenBird not directly from the gpoherjs project itself (https://github.com/gopherjs/gopherjs/search?q=post&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

Comment: @GreenBird although my older answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27034623/6309 is about POST.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/sourcegraph/webloop), it's not as easy as I thought since I am using windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to run JS code in Go, try Otto (https://github.com/robertkrimen/otto), it's a JS VM written in Go and very powerful.