# http.Get returns Protocol not available error

Tags: go

When I try to run this example at http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Get, it returns the following error

> 2009/11/10 23:00:00 Get http://www.google.com/robots.txt: dial tcp: Protocol not available

Any idea why?

Comment: What OS and Go version are you running?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The Go Playground does not allow HTTP requests. This has nothing to do with code. It is a security precaution enforced by the playground.