# Golang send http request sending twice instead of once

Tags: http, go

I am trying to do simple http post request using the following code:
[Golang code from another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24455606/1347587)

It's sending the http request twice (I tried both to my own web service and also to the Firebase messaging server). Anyone have any idea of what's wrong? Thank you.

**Edit**
Ignore me, figured out it's the AVG anti virus causing the problem. If I do:`go run program.go` then hit enter just once, AVG interrupts saying it has scan it and then let it run. This results in the http call twice. If I disable antivirus before running, then the http requrest is received only once on the other side. I've switched the antivirus on and off a few times to confirm this is the cause.

Comment: If you are using that *exact* code, then the request will not be sent twice; you must be executing it twice.

Comment: ...Unless the server returned a `Location` header, then the HTTP client will follow the redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in my edit, the cause was AVG anti virus. There was nothing in the console log indicating any part of the program was run twice. Not sure why the downvotes, I spend a few hours on this, move from Firebase messaging server to my own webserver to remove external dependency, and even read the source in net/http package.