# Posting a json message to a webserver inside a pod

Tags: go, kubernetes, http-post

I am new to kubernetes.
I have implemented a webserver inside a pod and set a Nodeport service for that pod.
I want to send a POST request with a custom message (in json) to a pod after it has been created and ready to use. I want to use the go client library for that matter. Could you please let me know how I can do that?
Which part of the library come to help?
Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to use the kubernetes client to do that, it's just a normal http request to the app running the the pod, but via the nodeport.

Comment: If it's just the simple post request you need info on, see [How do I send a json string request in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455147/how-do-i-send-a-json-string-in-a-post-request-in-go/24455606#24455606)

Comment: Hi @Matt, many thanks for your reply. Would you please elaborate your answer? the part that new and made me confused is  "but via the nodeport".

Comment: Sure thing, added an answer with some more detail on the kubernetes flow

Answer (score 1):

Say the go server runs on locally, you normally use `http://localhost:3000` to access it. The pod then has a `containerPort` of `3000`.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: go-web-deployment
  labels:
    app: GoWeb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: GoWeb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: GoWeb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: go-web
        image: me/go-web:1.0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

The Service is then an abstraction of that pod, that describes how to access 1 or many Pods running that service.

The `nodePort` of the service is `31024`.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: go-web-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: GoWeb
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      nodePort: 31024
```

The application is published on `http://node-ip:node-port` for the public to consume. Kubernetes manages the mappings between the node and the container in the background.

```
| User | -> | Node:nodePort | -> | Pod:containerPort |
```

The Kubernetes internal Service and Pod IP's are not often available to the outside world (unless you specifically set a cluster up that way). Whereas the nodes themselves will often carry an IP address that is routable/contactable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me to communicate with my pod. But I have to enable port-forward in order to send/receive traffic from the pod. Is there a way that we don't need to enable port-forward?

Comment: Enable port forward? You mean with `kubectl port-forward`? That's not a part of the mechanism described above.  A port forward is a way of tunnelling a connection to a Pod via the kubernetes API to test/debug things. Maybe read through the [Service docco](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types).

Comment: I am using minikube for my experiment and used "minikube ip" command to find the node-ip as suggested and when I use http://node-ip:node-port I got "Operation time out". This is why I used port-forward.